# Test if mutation triggered reactivity

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I ran into a problem with Vuex recently which turned out to be caused by mutation not triggering reactivity. I'm not sure how to detect if reactivity got triggered in unit tests without mounting component tho. What would be correct way to test it without mounting any component?

Answer (score 0):

Mutations are quite simple to test because they are just functions that rely entirely on their arguments. A trick is this: If you are using ES2015 modules and put your mutations inside your store.js file, you must export mutations as a named export, in addition to the default export.

Then to verify certain triggers are fired you could use the spies of [Sinon](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/sinon-chai/).

```
const state = { ... }

// export `mutations` as a named export
export const mutations = { ... }

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  mutations
})
```

Sample test using Mocha and Chai (you could use other libraries too):

```
// mutations.js
export const mutations = {
  triggerMutation: state => state.doSth
}
```

And the spec file:

```
// mutations.spec.js
var chai = require('chai');
var sinon = require('sinon');
var sinonChai = require('sinon-chai');
var mutations = require('store');
var expect = chai.expect;
chai.use(sinonChai);

const { mutate } = mutations

describe('mutations', () => {
  it('Mutate should trigger', () => {
    // set up your spy
    var spy = sinon.spy();

    // apply the mutation
    mutate(spy);

    // assert result
    expect(spy).to.have.been.calledWith('triggerMutation');
  })
})
```

Comment: That's not really what I have problem with, testing mutations is not a problem, but testing if this mutation will trigger updates in components is.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. You'll need to use a spying library like Sinon.js. Please see the updated answer.